# postgres query to check for records not falling between two time periods using the ISO WEEK number and year from DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

i do have a query which works fine but I was just wondering if there are other ways or alternate method to bettter this.

I have a table where i am fetching those records exceeding or do not fall between 1 year time interval however there is only the year and ISO week number column in the table (integer values).

basically the logic is to check ISO WEEK - YEAR  falls between 'current_date - interval '1 year'  AND current_date.

My query is as below :

```
 select *  from raj_weekly_records where 
    (date_dimension_week > extract(week from current_date) and date_dimension_year = extract(year from current_date) )
    or (date_dimension_week <  extract(week from current_date) and (extract(year from current_date)-date_dimension_year=1) )
    or(extract(year from current_date)-date_dimension_year>1);
```

Here date_dimension_week and date_dimension_year are the only integer parameters by which I need to check is there any other alternate or better way?.This code is working fine no issues here.

Comment: Could you post some data?

Comment: there is not much data here except data_dimension_week and date_dimension_year both integer type data.these are the only two columns I am using as this is for testing purpose.

Comment: I can only be sure of your desired output if you post it along some data.

Comment: the desired output is to just return all those records which do not fall in the ISOWEEKS between a duration of 1 year from the current date and there is only two columns currently in the table one for the year and other for the week(ISOWEEK ) Which both are of type integers.The data will be like this for ex : 2014(year) 14 (ISOWEEK0

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.  Convert the year/week to a numeric format:  YYYYWW.  That is, the year times 100 plus the week number.  Then you can do the logic with a single comparison:

```
select * 
from raj_weekly_records
where date_dimension_year * 100 + date_dimension_week
          not between (extract(year from current_date) - 1) * 100 + extract(week from current_date) and
                      extract(year from current_date) * 100 + extract(week from current_date)
```

(There might be an off-by one error, depending on whether the weeks at the ends are included or excluded.)

Comment: excellent it works too and faster too thanks...I like to see other responses as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from raj_weekly_records
where
    date_trunc('week',
        '0001-01-01 BC'::date + date_dimension_year * interval '1 year'
    )
    + (date_dimension_week + 1) * interval '1 week'
    - interval '1 day'
    not between
    current_date - interval '1 year' and current_date
```